# Redirect URI mismatch in Google Api

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, yii2

Hi I am using Yii authclient for social media login purpose.Now, I am trying to login my site with using Google.

main.php

```
'google' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\GoogleOAuth',
                'clientId' => '****************',
                'clientSecret' => '***************',                    
            ],
```

Whenever i am trying to login with Google it returns error code 400.

```
request details:

scope=profile email
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost/project/buyold/frontend/web/customer/account/auth?authclient=google
xoauth_displayname=My Application
client_id=***********************************
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code or app setting.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are using a redirect URL that does not match any of what you have added to the Credentials of your application in Google Developer Console.

If the Authorized redirect URIs section does not have the URL you are using it will return 400.

Check your Authorized redirect URIs, add yours if its not added and please note that I don't really recommend keeping the URL with this format, here is an example of how to configure your virtual host with [Apache or Nginx](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)